# What is the name for a non-owner user profile?

Tags: profiles

I have an Android tablet with two user profiles. One is designated the "owner". How do I refer to the other profile (for example, when posting questions here or logging tickets for an app)?

I'm looking for a short (and preferably official) term that Android experts would immediately recognize.

*Suggested tag (based on answer): secondary-profile*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android 5.0+, there is an option for multiple Users & Profiles, which is under `Settings > Users` and is titled `Users & profiles`. It is initially populated with a `Guest` User as well as the `Owner` User. To refer to non-owner Users & Profiles I would use and recognize `Secondary User/Profile` (unless specifically asking about the `Guest` User, which I would call `Guest User`)

User accounts provide full access to Apps & Services.

Android 5.0+ Tablets (this feature does not appear to be on Phones) allow for User Profiles, such as the `Restricted User Profile`, which can be set up to restrict what Apps and Services can be used by this user.

`Accounts` is a separate setting within Android's Settings. Each User Profile can have any number of Accounts set up (Emails, Pushbullet, etc.). These accounts are unique to each User.

Comment: so should I refer to "user profiles" rather than "user accounts"?

Comment: Was in the process of adding the Account caveat. Profiles and Accounts are different. You can have multiple users set up profiles (e.g., my wife and I have a profile), and within the profiles, set up multiple accounts (e.g., I have 3 Gmail accounts under my Profile, my wife has 1)

Comment: updated my question with correct terminology :)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that Lollipop introduces the concept of managed provisioning, which is built on top of the multi-user features discussed here. Basically, this allows the same app to be present more than once in a single launcher, and each instance has it's own 'uid', data directory, etc.